# Problem adding training phrases in several dialogflow intents, whit several acounts

Tags: android-intent, addition, dialogflow-es, phrase

Today we had a problem with dialogflow.
We have tried adding training phrases in several dialogflow intents, from different accounts, without getting the changes applied. An agent message appears saying constantly starting training, without finishing and without saving changes.
Has anyone ever had a similar problem? It's the first time it happens to us.

adding training phrases in several dialogflow intents, from different accounts,and getting the changes applied.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like we're encountering a similar issue. Could it be possible that this problem is related to the Document AI service? The Google Status website indicates that the service is currently experiencing some issues.

Comment: We have been experiencing the problem since Sunday.  The biggest mistake yesterday.  Today it took 27 minutes to include a single training phrase.  How have you experienced failure?

Comment: We can update the intents and training phrases via the API, but the agent training process never stopped.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, we experienced similar situations. Today the training time was decreasing. It went from not stopping to 27 minutes, 17, 8.5 until reaching 2 minutes at 17 hours. Now it is working correctly.